# Splitting Regex into Array

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string of elements on multiple lines (but i can change this to being all on one line if necessary) and I want to split it on the <section> element. I thought this would be easy, just str.split(regex), or even str.split('<section') but it's not working. It never breaks the sections out.

I've tried using a regular expression SecRegex = /<section.*?>[\s\S]*?</section>/; var fndSection = result.split(SecRegex);

Tried var fndSection = result.split('<section');

I've looked all over the net and from what I've found one of the two methods above should have worked.

result = '

```
<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title>
<section id="Thoery">
<title>theory Section</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Theory Para 0 </title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter> <title>Chapter Title</title>
<section id="Section ID">
<title>Section Title</title>
<para0>
<title>Para0 Title</title>
<para>blah blah</para>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<line>Title</line>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<list>Title</list>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<ipbchap>
<tags></tags>
</ipbchap>

</body>
<rear>
<tags></tags>
</rear>
</doc>'
```

Code

```
SecRegex = /<section.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/section>/;
var fndSection = result.split(SecRegex);

console.log("result string " + fndSection);
```

This is the result I'm getting from the code I have

```
result string <chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title> , , , , <chapter id="chap1"> <para0> <title></title></para0> </chapter> 
result string <chapter id="chap1"> <para0> <title></title></para0> </chapter> 
result string <chapter
```

As you can see

What I want is a string of <section>.*?</section> into an array

Thank you everyone for looking at this and helping me. I appreciate all your help.

Maxine

Comment: [You shouldn't use regular expressions to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).  I would use an html parser.

Comment: it's an SGML document

Comment: The question mark in '/<section.?>[\s\S]?</section>/;' will only match max one character. You need to replace it with a star '*', that will mach zero or more characters!

Answer (score 2):

Your expression looks pretty great! You might just want to slightly modify it, maybe to something similar to:

```
/<section[a-z="'\s]+>([\s\S]*?)<\/section>/gmi
```

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0wv9WG/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /<section[a-z="'\s]+>([\s\S]*?)<\/section>/gmi;
const str = `<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title>
<section id="Thoery">
<title>theory Section</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Theory Para 0 </title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

---

In case you might want to capture the section tags as well, you can simply wrap your [entire expression in a capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/ikRWFn/1):

```js
const regex = /(<section[a-z="'\s]+>([\s\S]*?)<\/section>)/gmi;
const str = `<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title>
<section id="Thoery">
<title>theory Section</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Theory Para 0 </title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>`;
const subst = `\n$1\n`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: \n', result);
```

Comment: thank you this was great. I'm getting the sections now but I'm also getting the <chapter elements. I thought using a specific regex would only give me the <section elements. Is this not correct?

Comment: Hi! So take the input string and replace all the <chapter>elements? I'm not sure this will work because I have whole <chapter></chapter> and also <chapter><section> elements

Comment: the end result to all this is I'm trying to get the last <section> element and add a </chapter> element to the end of it. That's my big headache because I'm honestly stumped on it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *split* the string - you want to *extract* the data that matches your pattern from it. You can do that using [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match). Note that you need to add the `g` flag to get all matches:

```js
var result = `<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title>
<section id="Thoery">
<title>theory Section</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Theory Para 0 </title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter> <title>Chapter Title</title>
<section id="Section ID">
<title>Section Title</title>
<para0>
<title>Para0 Title</title>
<para>blah blah</para>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<line>Title</line>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<list>Title</list>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<ipbchap>
<tags></tags>
</ipbchap>

</body>
<rear>
<tags></tags>
</rear>
</doc>`;
// the g flag is added ---------------------↓
SecRegex = /<section.*?>[\s\S]*?<\/section>/g;
var fndSection = result.match(SecRegex);


console.log("result string ", fndSection);
```

However, you are better off parsing the DOM and extracting the information you want from there - this is simple using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser):

```js
var result = `<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2"> <title>THEORY</title>
<section id="Thoery">
<title>theory Section</title>
<para0 verstatus="ver">
<title>Theory Para 0 </title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap1">
<para0><title></title></para0>
</chapter>

<chapter> <title>Chapter Title</title>
<section id="Section ID">
<title>Section Title</title>
<para0>
<title>Para0 Title</title>
<para>blah blah</para>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="Next section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<line>Title</line>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="More sections">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<list>Title</list>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<section id="section">
<title>title</title>
<para0>
<title>Title</title>
<text>blah blah</text>
</para0>
</section>

<ipbchap>
<tags></tags>
</ipbchap>

</body>
<rear>
<tags></tags>
</rear>
</doc>`

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/html");

var sections = [...doc.getElementsByTagName("section")];
var fndSection = sections.map(section => section.outerHTML)
console.log(fndSection);
```

Comment: I put it into an array because I'm trying to get a count of the section elements so I can take action on the last occurance of a section within a chapter

Answer (score 1):

Do not use RegEx on HTML (or any cousin of HTML). Collect your `<section>s` into a NodeList. Convert that NodeList into an Array. Convert each Node into a String. This could be done in one line:

> ```
> const strings = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('section')).map(section => section.outerHTML);
> ```

The following demo is a breakdown of the example above.

```js
// Collect all <section>s into a NodeList
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

// Convert NodeList into an Array
const array = Array.from(sections);

/*
Iterate through Array -- on each <section>...
convert it into a String
*/
const strings = array.map(section => section.outerHTML);

// View array as a template literal for a cleaner look
console.log(`${strings}`);

// Verifying it's an array of mutiple elements
console.log(strings.length);

// Verifying that they are in fact strings
console.log(typeof strings[0]);
```

```html
<chapter id="chap1">
  <para0>
    <title></title>
  </para0>
</chapter>

<chapter id="chap2">
  <title>THEORY</title>
  <section id="Thoery">
    <title>theory Section</title>
    <para0 verstatus="ver">
      <title>Theory Para 0 </title>
      <text>blah blah</text>
    </para0>
  </section>

  <section id="Next section">
    <title>title</title>
    <para0>
      <title>Title</title>
      <text>blah blah</text>
    </para0>
  </section>

  <section id="More sections">
    <title>title</title>
    <para0>
      <title>Title</title>
      <text>blah blah</text>
    </para0>
  </section>

  <section id="section">
    <title>title</title>
    <para0>
      <title>Title</title>
      <text>blah blah</text>
    </para0>
  </section>

  <chapter id="chap1">
    <para0>
      <title></title>
    </para0>
  </chapter>

  <chapter id="chap1">
    <para0>
      <title></title>
    </para0>
  </chapter>

  <chapter>
    <title>Chapter Title</title>
    <section id="Section ID">
      <title>Section Title</title>
      <para0>
        <title>Para0 Title</title>
        <para>blah blah</para>
      </para0>
    </section>

    <section id="Next section">
      <title>title</title>
      <para0>
        <line>Title</line>
        <text>blah blah</text>
      </para0>
    </section>

    <section id="More sections">
      <title>title</title>
      <para0>
        <list>Title</list>
        <text>blah blah</text>
      </para0>
    </section>

    <section id="section">
      <title>title</title>
      <para0>
        <title>Title</title>
        <text>blah blah</text>
      </para0>
    </section>

    <ipbchap>
      <tags></tags>
    </ipbchap>
```